# Closure may outlive the current function even if the lifetime is marked

Tags: rust, closures, lifetime, borrow-checker

```rust
fn get_closeures<'a>(x: &'a i64) -> Vec<Box<dyn Fn() + 'a>> {
    let mut ret: Vec<Box<dyn Fn() -> ()>> = Vec::new();
    ret.push(Box::new(|| println!("{}", x + 1)));
    ret.push(Box::new(|| println!("{}", x + 2)));

    ret
}

fn main() {
    let x: i64 = 100;
    {
        let closures = get_closeures(&x);
        for closure in closures {
            closure();
        }
    }
}
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=5515a794a91096c4b7ffa076bd4f642e)

lead to the errors

```
error[E0373]: closure may outlive the current function, but it borrows `x`, which is owned by the current function
 --> src/main.rs:3:23
  |
3 |     ret.push(Box::new(|| println!("{}", x + 1)));
  |                       ^^                - `x` is borrowed here
  |                       |
  |                       may outlive borrowed value `x`
  |
note: closure is returned here
 --> src/main.rs:6:5
  |
6 |     ret
  |     ^^^
help: to force the closure to take ownership of `x` (and any other referenced variables), use the `move` keyword
  |
3 |     ret.push(Box::new(move || println!("{}", x + 1)));
  |                       ++++
```

My question is that I have mark the lifetime of the argument `x` stored must be longer than the closures stored into vector. Why does compiler stop me to borrow x?

I know that I can just add `move` keyword on the closure to fix it. But If x is not a i64 but a non Copy struct, then this method should not work.

Also, I think there is no memory problem inside my code, how to convince the rust compiler to believe it?

Comment: without move closure would borrow the ref to x so `&&i64` with move you copy the reference `&i64` and this is now ok cause the lifetime of this reference is the one you wanted contrary to the double ref lifetime that is link to the function scope.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that `x` is not of type `i64`, but instead of type `&i64`, i.e. *reference to* `i64`. So `x` will always be `Copy` even if the underlying type isn't. Example:

```
fn get_closeures<'a>(x: &'a str) -> Vec<Box<dyn Fn() + 'a>> {
    let mut ret: Vec<Box<dyn Fn() -> ()>> = Vec::new();
    ret.push(Box::new(move || println!("{}", x)));
    ret.push(Box::new(move || println!("{}", x)));

    ret
}

fn main() {
    let x: String = "azerty".to_string();
    {
        let closures = get_closeures(&x);
        for closure in closures {
            closure();
        }
    }
}
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=47818f5da2faf171eab39afcdb77300d)

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that without the `move` suggested by the compiler the local `x` is referenced and only that reference is stored in the closure. But `x` is indeed freed at the end of `get_closures` so that reference is now dangling. To fix it you can simply apply the compilers suggestions, add `move` in front of every closure.

The move will **not** copy the `T` behind the reference but the reference itself which is exactly what you want.

Comment: [Here](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=3dbbb522111e2e6fa67c255f2433477f) an example with a non-copyable type illustrating your description

Answer (score 0):

You could give the `&x` parameter to each closure separately:

```
fn get_closures() -> Vec<fn(&i64)> {
    let mut ret: Vec<fn(&i64)> = vec![];
    ret.push(|x| println!("{}", x + 1));
    ret.push(|x| println!("{}", x + 2));

    ret
}
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=release&edition=2021&gist=415fba80f9fc1f7321d6a0342afe4db6)